# FCM notification in android. How to show all notification when app is in foreground

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I build android native app with FCM notification but is seems that default scenario when application is in foreground
Notifications overwrite each other's. how to prevent that and show all notifications when app is in foreground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason of that issue
when onMessageReceived get fired and create notification I give it static id with 0
notificationManager.notify(0, not)
instead of that I tried to give it unique id, so I used current time instead of zero
notificationManager.notify(System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(), not)